# I have some problem using "xOffset" in altair. The altair API code does not work for me

Tags: altair

Here is the code:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame({"Category":list("AAABBBCCC"),
                     "Group":list("xyzxyzxyz"),
                     "Value":[0.1, 0.6, 0.9, 0.7, 0.2, 1.1, 0.6, 0.1, 0.2]})

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x="Category:N",
    y="Value:Q",
    xOffset="Group:N",
    color="Group:N"
)
```

It says the error:

SchemaValidationError: Invalid specification

```
    altair.vegalite.v4.schema.core.FacetedEncoding, validating 'additionalProperties'

    Additional properties are not allowed ('xOffset' was unexpected)
```

Comment: You need to upgrade to Altair 5+ to use the xOffset encoding

Answer (score 0):

Adding my comment as an answer so that this question gets marked as solved: The solution is to update to Altair 5+ where the `xOffset` encoding was introduced.